# search document values within a text in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find all document values which are within a text/string:

Example:

Imagine I have the **tag** collection with the following documents:

```
db.tag.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7107c55b2acc61000bc8"), "name" : "star" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"), "name" : "star wars" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7117c55b2acc61000bca"), "name" : "spider" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537087d16ac5b5f6f58f0b1b"), "name" : "starting" }
```

I need something like this (example in mongodb shell):

```
db.tag.find({"name": { $subStrOF: "star wars episode VII" }})

returning this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7107c55b2acc61000bc8"), "name" : "star" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"), "name" : "star wars" }
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which version of mongod you are using?

Comment: I have tested "text" in my local db and it works fine.. check my answer

Comment: I am using mongodb 2.6.1, this is not working with executing db.tag.find({$text:{$search:"star wars episode VII"}}) it gives me "epi-VII" in the results which I don't need, **I am looking for full words** in tag collection (e.g. [star, wars, epidose, VII]). **epi-VII is a substring**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using $where, example below:

Command:

```
db.tag.find({$where:"'star wars episode VII'.search("star") >= 0"})
```

The output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f7107c55b2acc61000bc8"), "name" : "star" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"), "name" : "star wars" }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Start the mongod process with  command line options

```
--setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

Example:

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

Then in your mongo shell, create an index for name in tag collection

```
db.tag.ensureIndex({name : "text"});
```

Now you can query using text:

```
db.tag.runCommand("text", {search : "star wars episode"});
```

This will return you something like this

```
{
        "queryDebugString" : "star||||||",
        "language" : "english",
        "results" : [
                {
                        "score" : 1.1,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("536f7107c55b2acc61000bc8"),
                                "name" : "star"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "score" : 0.75,
                        "obj" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("536f710fc55b2acc61000bc9"),
                                "name" : "star wars"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "stats" : {
                "nscanned" : 2,
                "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                "n" : 2,
                "nfound" : 2,
                "timeMicros" : 152
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

To get only the results:

```
db.tag.runCommand("text", {search : "star wars episode"}).results
```

I have tested it with my local DB and it works fine. please check it

For more info about text : **[Mongo DOCs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/command/text/)**

BTW from mongoDB 2.6: [DOCS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)

```
db.tag.find({$text : {$search : "star wars episode VII"}});
```

Comment: Hi mohamedrias, I already tested this, text-search is working for me as you can see in my question, the problem is that is filtering by substring and I need to search by full string. I have documented this on my question. Thanks